# The value of $\sin{(135^\circ-2\alpha)}\cdot\sin{(\alpha-45^\circ)+\cos^2{(75^\circ-\alpha)}}-2\sin{(\alpha-30^\circ)}$ when $\alpha=60^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of the expression $$\sin{(135^\circ-2\alpha)}\cdot\sin{(\alpha-45^\circ)+\cos^2{(75^\circ-\alpha)}}-2\sin{(\alpha-30^\circ)}$$ when $\alpha=60^\circ$.

I don't know if I am supposed to simplify the given expression, but I just put $\alpha=60^\circ$ to get $$\sin(135^\circ-120^\circ)\cdot\sin(60^\circ+45^\circ)+\cos^2(75^\circ-60^\circ)-2\sin(60^\circ-30^\circ)=\\=\sin15^\circ.\sin105^\circ+\cos^215^\circ-2\sin30^\circ.$$
What can I do next? If we can't simplify the given expression, what is the point of the problem? I mean are they checking if we can multiply and add numbers?

Comment: The result should be a number, since there is no variable left in the expression. Presumably, you know the value of $\sin 30^\circ$, and you can calculate the others using trig formulas, for example $\sin 15^\circ = \sin \left(45^\circ - 30^\circ\right)$.

Comment: 60+45 should be 60-45

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a simpler question than what is thought to be.

Replace $\alpha$ with $60^\circ$, just remember

$\sin 30^\circ =\frac{1}{2}, \sin ^2x + \cos ^2 x=1$

Then,

$\sin15^\circ.\sin15^\circ+\cos^215^\circ-2\sin30^\circ\\=1-2\cdot \frac{1}{2}=0.$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

You could first use the following formula, known as one of the [product to sum formulae](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html) among other names,
$$\sin x\sin y\equiv\frac{1}{2}(\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y))$$
to evaluate $\sin 15^\circ\sin105^\circ$ without having to explicitly evaluate $\sin 15^\circ$ and $\sin105^\circ$.

You could then use the double angle formula for $\cos$ to write $\cos^2 15^\circ$ in terms of $\cos30^\circ$ as @Ritam_Dasgupta suggested.

---

**NOTE**

As @Empy2 has noted, your working is wrong; you have a $+$ where there should be a $-$.

---

I hope that helps. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Notice that $\sin 105°=\cos 15°$. Then you have to use the formulae:
$$\frac {\cos {2\theta}+1}{2}=\cos^2 \theta$$
And,
$$\sin{2\theta}=2\sin \theta \cos \theta$$
Can you do it now? If you do it this way, you won't have to calculate trigonometric ratios for $15°,$which can be evaluated, but are slightly complicated.